# Why did my sysprep for Windows 7 Professional come up as Ultimate when I rebooted?

Tags: sysprep

I used sysprep for Windows 7 Professional.  I don't even own Ultimate.  When I rebooted my sysprepped machine, it came up as Ultimate.  How can this happen?  Is there a way to make it professional again?

Comment: Is this a personal or company computer?  If a company is running a KMS server windows will activate against whatever license the KMS server has.

Comment: It is because I am an idiot. There was no error except by me.